# Close all open documents of a Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Does Visual Studio have a way to close all open documents that belong to the same project?

I am currently using the Productivity Power Tools Extension that can already color documents by project type, but I couldn't find an option to close all documents of a project there.

Searching the Quick Launch for "close" did not yield any results either.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on a tab?

Comment: Yes, but the only options there are "Close", "Close All But This" and "Close All Documents" neither of which do what I want.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Misunderstood before. Hope you find something useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension you can [sort](https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/addins/sorter.html) tabs by project with [super groups](https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/visual_studio_tab_grouping.html#SuperGroup) and then close all open documents that belong to the same project with the [Close super group](https://blog.tabsstudio.com/2017/06/16/super-commands-for-super-groups/) tab context menu command.